# Pattern matching with vector

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have an expression:

```
{((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Sin[t])/(4*Pi*R0), -1/4*((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Cos[t])/(Pi*R0), 0}
```

And I would like it to recognize this pattern

```
%/.{-Sin[t],Cos[t],0}-> ET
```

such that

```
{((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Sin[t])/(4*Pi*R0), -1/4*((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Cos[t])/(Pi*R0), 0} /.{-Sin[t],Cos[t],0}-> ET
```

should result in

```
-ET (-2*m*n + B*R0^2)/(4*Pi*R0)
```

or something the like. It however does not work. Who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your result has a typo. Instead of `-ET (2*m*n + B*R0^2)/(4*Pi*R0)` it should read `-ET (-2*m*n + B*R0^2)/(4*Pi*R0)`, otherwise there is no solution.

A further problem is the minus sign in front of the Cos term. MMA always uses the full form of an expression for matching. Look at:

```
((-2 m n + B R0^2) Cos[t])/(4 \[Pi] R0) // FullForm
(* Times[Rational[1,4],Power[Pi,-1],Power[R0,-1],Plus[Times[-2,m,n],Times[B,Power[R0,2]]],Cos[t]] *)
```

and

```
-(((-2 m n + B R0^2) Cos[t])/(4 \[Pi] R0)) // FullForm
(* Times[Rational[-1,4],Power[Pi,-1],Power[R0,-1],Plus[Times[-2,m,n],Times[B,Power[R0,2]]],Cos[t]] *)
```

You see, the minus is integrated in the Rational[-1,4]. Therefore, for matching, the minus can not be matched separately. Here is how you can do it:

```
{((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Sin[t])/(4*Pi*R0), -1/4*((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Cos[t])/(Pi*R0),  0} /. { x__ Sin[t], y__ Cos[t], 0} :> ET y
```

[image]

Comment: I have corrected the wrong minus sign, it was typo. That the integration of the sign into the fraction hampers the pattern detection is a bit odd, but I suppose there have to be some limits in pattern detection otherwise any pattern would be everywhere I suppose. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Consider vector projection using the dot product. Let `v` be the input vector and `p` be the pattern:

```
v = {((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Sin[t])/(4*Pi*R0), -1/4*((-2*m*n + B*R0^2)*Cos[t])/(Pi*R0), 0};
p = {-Sin[t], Cos[t], 0};
```

Then the parts of the vector which are in line with the given pattern are:

```
Simplify[v.p/Norm[p], Element[t, Reals]]
```

> (2 m n - B R0^2)/(4 π R0)

You may multiply this by `ET`, if you wish. For other expression the `Simplify` may not be necessary to achieve a nice result, and I have assumed `t` is a real number here for simplicity. If that is not necessarily the case, this method may not be appropriate.

Note also that the non-conforming parts of the vector are given by:

```
Simplify[v-v.p/Norm[p], Element[t, Reals]]
```

> {0, 0, 0}

In general two vectors will not be perfectly aligned with each other, so this term is normally non-zero. This is the part of your vector which does not co-align with your given pattern.

Comment: OK, I see, I have also tried with Solve[b p = v, b] which also works.